# Constructor error by Abstract class

Tags: c#

Iam working on a application with a abstract class.

My abstract class = Werknemer
The subclasses = Ober and Kok

Now i got a error when i add this line in my form

`Kok a = new Kok();`

"does not contain a constructor that takes 0"

Do i something wrong?

My abstract class:

```
abstract class Werknemer
{

    public string Naam { get; private set; }
    public double FTE { get; private set; }
    public int WerknemersCode { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DatumIndienst { get; private set; }
    public string WerktBijRestaurant { get; private set; }
    public decimal FooiUitkering { get; private set; }

    public  Werknemer(string Naam, Adres Adres, double FTE, int WerknemersCode, DateTime DatumIndienst, string Res)
    {
        this.Naam = Naam;
        this.FTE = FTE;
        this.WerknemersCode = WerknemersCode;
        this.DatumIndienst = DatumIndienst;
        this.WerktBijRestaurant = Res;
    }
    public String AlsString()
    {
        return Naam;
    }

     public abstract String MaakSchoon();




}
```

MY other subclasses :

```
class Ober : Werknemer
{
    public bool AllRounder { get; private set; }
    public bool Bediening { get; private set; }
    public decimal Fooi { get; private set; }

    public Ober(string Naam, Adres Adres, double FTE, int WerknemersCode, DateTime DatumIndienst, string res): base(Naam, Adres, FTE, WerknemersCode, DatumIndienst, res)

    {
    //   this.AllRounder = AllRounder;
  //     this.Bediening = Bediening;
      //  this.FooienPot = FooienPot;
    }
    public String ToString()
    {
        return null;
    }
    public override String MaakSchoon()
    {
        return "Ober";
    }
```

Other subclass

```
class Kok : Werknemer
{
    public bool Leadkok { get; private set; }
    public string Specialiteit { get; private set; }

    public Kok(string Naam, Adres Adres, double FTE, int WerknemersCode, DateTime DatumIndienst, string res) : base (
        Naam, Adres, FTE, WerknemersCode, DatumIndienst, res)
    {

    //    this.Leadkok = Leadkok;
     //   this.Specialiteit = Specialiteit;
    }
    public String ToString()
    {
        return null;
    }
   public override String MaakSchoon()
    {
        return "kok";            
    }
```

Comment: In your third code block, you declare the constructor `public Kok(string Naam, Adres Adres, double FTE, int WerknemersCode, DateTime DatumIndienst, string res)` which has 6 parameters. But you invoke it with 0 arguments (`new Kok()`).

Comment: You have no default constructor defined.  And what's more, you aren't calling the parameters you overloaded 'Kok' with in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Kok` type doesn't have a parameterless constructor, so you will need to pass the parameters it expects when you instantiate it, or a add a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 7):

When you define a constructor with parameters - you automatically 'hide' the default one.

i.e. you need to explicitly define it.

Just add...

```
public Kok(){}
```

and you should be fine.

**Your base class expects some 'sensible' parameters as input** - so you need to see what that is for your case at hand. (as improved by @Mudu)

Comment: Actually, the default constructor must *invoke the `base` constructor* with reasonable default values instead of passed ones as in the OP's code: `public Kok() : base(...) {}`

Comment: of course @Mudu - this was a fast pointer - OP needs to fill in the gaps.